# Why are my UIImageViews moving on startup?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview

I placed 16 UIImageViews on a storyboard in specific spots, and when I run the application, the UIImageViews are placed differently along the y-axis, meaning, that some of the UIImageViews appear more up or down then they are supposed to. I didn't change the UIInterfaceOrientation or anything, the orientation is portrait like normal.

One thing I did was hook each UIImageView up to an outlet in my viewController.h file so I can alter one of the properties later on (just background color, not frame). Other than that everything else I did seemed normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using auto-layout?

You need to ensure that the auto-layout box is *unchecked* in the File Inspector for your view controller.

Comment: I'm using iPhone 6.1 simulator, and I don't know if I'm using auto layout. I'm using whatever the default is

Comment: You can check if you are using auto layout by selecting your view controller and open the file inspector. Is the auto layout box checked or unchecked?